# Getting X and Y coordinate of android screen using accessibility services

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am working on an app where i want to track all the touch/click on the android screen... I am not referring to tracking of clicks on my app but i want to track the overall screen. Where the user is clicking on the screen.

I am getting boundsInParent: Rect(left, top, right, bottom) & boundsInScreen: Rect(left, top, right, bottom)

Is there a way i can get the actual X & Y coordinates? Can MotionEvent be used with Accessibility service? If yes then can someone help me on this.

What is the right way to achieve this. I will appreciate your responses.

Attached is the screenshot for reference which is highlighted in Yellow.

[Screenshot of Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDrjq.png)

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same issue currently